# tempfile not being given the right name. $BASHPID is changing?

Tags: bash

I thought that this should be straight forward.  Generate a temp file and output it.  Apparently, there's some strangeness happening behind the scenes.

```
function x {
  cat $2 > /tmp/$BASHPID.$$;
  cat /tmp/$BASHPID.$$;  # < FAILS because $BASHPID has changed???
};
echo a>/tmp/junk;
x $$ /tmp/junk &
```

This works however:

```
function x {
  local tmp=/tmp/$BASHPID.$$;
  cat $2 > $tmp;
  cat $tmp;  # < WORKS!
};
echo a>/tmp/junk;
x $$ /tmp/junk &
```

What exactly is `$BASHPID`?  I thought it is basically like `$$` except if executed in a subprocess, it will get the subprocesses PID.  When executing cat, is it actually getting cat's PID?

Comment: You are making a serious mistake in reimplementing [mktemp(1)](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?mktemp) poorly without examining the history of security problems with your approach. In particular, nvestigate why tempfile(1) was deprecated. (Sorry, no good link offhand.)

Comment: By quick glance, http://www.linuxsecurity.com/content/view/115462/151/ seems to collect the relevant issues.

Comment: Thanks, but I wasn't worried about security.  This was just a curiosity that I found.  I did this for speed.  However, I'll keep it in mind when I write other code.

Comment: "For speed" would dictate `x () { local tmp=$(mktemp); cat "$2" >$tmp; cat $tmp; }` or in other words, learning the secure idiom is less effort.

Comment: `$(mktemp)` spawns another process, which is what I was trying to avoid and doesn't negate that this is not expected behaviour at first glance.

Comment: @Adrian: Practically every bash command spawns another process. Nonetheless, `bash` is pretty snappy. Avoiding `mktemp` is premature optimization. That's all irrelevant to your question, but perhaps not to your actual work. :)

Comment: No, it's not premature.  I was working on the script for a while before I posted this question.  But thanks for your concern. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a particular instance of a general issue with subshells in bash. You don't need `$BASHPID` to see it.

The [bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Simple-Command-Expansion) is quite clear that redirections and assignments are expanded after all other words have been expanded:

> When a simple command is executed, the shell performs the following expansions, assignments, and redirections, from left to right.
>
> 1. The words that the parser has marked as variable assignments (those preceding the command name) and redirections are **saved for later processing**.
> 2. The words that are not variable assignments or redirections are expanded (see Shell Expansions). If any words remain after expansion, the first word is taken to be the name of the command and the remaining words are the arguments. 
>      …

Consequently, the following should not be surprising:

```
$ unset tmp; a=$tmp eval "echo ${tmp:=foo} \$a"
foo foo
```

Here, `${tmp:=foo}` is expanded before `a=$tmp` with the result that `a=foo` is passed into the environment for the evaluation of `echo foo $a`.

From here, things get murkier. The manual says that redirections are expanded before assignments (actually points 3 and 4; I can't get markdown to co-operate):

> 1. Redirections are performed as described above (see Redirections).
> 2. The text after the ‘=’ in each variable assignment undergoes tilde expansion, parameter expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion, and quote removal before being assigned to the variable.

But as we see here, assignments seem to be expanded first:

```
$ unset tmp; a=$tmp eval <${tmp:=foo} 'echo :$a:'
::
$ unset tmp; <${tmp:=foo} a=$tmp eval 'echo :$a:'
::
```

And while the manual is explicit that once `bash` determines that a command is an external utility:

> the shell executes the named program in a separate execution environment *(from the next section of the manual.)*

it's not explicit how much of the word expansion in assignments and redirects is done in the command's execution environment and how much is done in the original environment. And, indeed, the behaviour is not easily predictable.

From experimentation (with bash 4.2), we can see that:

1. Assignments are expanded in the parent environment.
2. Redirections are expanded in the child environment, if there is one.
3. In the case of builtins, no child is created, and redirections are expanded in the parent:

```
$ unset tmp; a=${tmp:=foo} cat </dev/null; echo tmp=$tmp
tmp=foo
$ unset tmp; >${tmp:=foo} cat </dev/null; echo tmp=$tmp
tmp=
$ unset tmp; >${tmp:=foo} echo </dev/null; echo tmp=$tmp
tmp=foo
```

All of the above is, at least, reasonable, although the order of assignments and redirections should, IMHO, be documented more accurately. However, the following -- where the expansion in a `stdin` redirection is evaluated twice if the file doesn't exist -- is certainly a bug:

```
$ tmp=0; /bin/echo .. <$((tmp+=2)); echo $tmp
bash: 4: No such file or directory
0

# As expected, with a builtin tmp is altered in the parent environment
$ tmp=0; echo .. <$((tmp+=2)); echo $tmp
bash: 4: No such file or directory
4
```

---

Since `$BASHPID` is always the pid of the process in which `$BASHPID` is actually expanded, all of these various issues also affect its value. In general, I think, the only safe rule is:

- **Do not** modify the environment or depend on `$BASHPID` anywhere other than:

  - a stand-alone assignment, or
  - a simple parameter expansion in a command or argument word.

---

As a side note, the best way to generate a name for a temporary file is with the `mktemp` utility.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that `cat` isn't a shell builtin.  As such, the shell needs to `fork` and `exec`.

This causes the `BASHPID` in the following line:

```
cat $2 > /tmp/$BASHPID.$$;
```

to be the PID of the child process.  Note that the special variable `$$`, on the other hand, is expanded before forking.  As such, you could think of it as saying:

```
cat $2 > /tmp/$BASHPID.xxxxx
```

where `xxxxx` refers to the shell process executing the function.

---

A simpler way to observe that would be by saying:

```
touch $BASHPID; cat $BASHPID > $BASHPID
```

You'd observe that the filename would be different from the contents of the file.  Essentially implying that the `BASHPID` changed.

On the other hand, saying:

```
touch $BASHPID; echo $BASHPID > $BASHPID
```

would result in the file contents being same as it's name.

Comment: `$$` doesn't change, so it doesn't matter when it is expanded. OTOH, `$BASHPID` does change, and it does matter.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the rule is:

> The right-hand side of the redirection of a simple *external command* is executed in a subshell (in the same subshell that `exec`s the external command).

This follows the “rule” 1) fork, 2) prepare redirections and 3) exec.

Here are a few things that confirm the rule:

```
$ i=0; echo > $((i++)); echo "1=$i"; /bin/echo > $((i++)); echo "2=$i"
1=1
2=1
$ ( /bin/echo "$BASHPID.$$" ) > "$BASHPID.$$"
$ ls
22417.21291
$ cat 22417.21291
22417.21291
$ i=0; echo > $((i++)); echo "1=$i"; { /bin/echo; } > $((i++)); echo "2=$i"
1=1
2=2
```

What will work is to group your command:

```
function x {
  { cat "$2"; } > /tmp/$BASHPID.$$; # <--- use a group here
  cat /tmp/$BASHPID.$$; # <--- this now works!
};
```

---

Note that this behavior is not true in `sh`. Compare:

```
$ sh -c 'i=0; echo > $((i=i+1)); echo "$i"; /bin/echo > $((i=i+1)); echo "$i"'
1
2
$ bash -c 'i=0; echo > $((i=i+1)); echo "$i"; /bin/echo > $((i=i+1)); echo "$i"'
1
1
```

In Bash it's weird, clunky, and I'm not even sure it's the wanted behavior; moreover it's not documented at all. We'll have to do with it.

Comment: So what we're seeing is a bug?

Comment: @Adrian I'm not sure we can call it a bug… yet you can try to file a bug report and see what reply you get.

Comment: @Adrian, since `BASHPID` isn't specified by POSIX, and its behavior in this respect isn't covered in the bash manual in either direction, there's no specification for it to break. This is one of the advantages of relying only on documented semantics. :)